# Как реализовать схему сайта с 2мя меню

Tags: php, bootstrap

Хочу реализовать схему сайта на bootstrap, но не знаю как подступиться.
Вопросы: index.php должен содержать вызовы всех основных блоков header, nav, sidebar, main, footer. Здесь все понятно. Но, во-первых, каждый клик по горизонтальному меню должен менять и содержимое пунктов sidebar, у каждого верхнего раздела они свои. Соответственно каждый клик пунктов sidebar загружает свой контент в блок main.
Прочитал где-то, что в случае реализации 2-х меню на bootstrap одновременно показывается только 1шт.
Если это правда, то такую схему на php-bootstrap не реализовать?
Bootstrap хотел выбрать для возможности адаптации мобильной версии.
Но здесь тоже натыкаюсь на вопрос. В случае сворачивания меню, у меня оно должно получиться 3-х уровневым, а это значит текущее представление 2х меню и его свернутый вариант - разные по содержанию.
Помогите советом по реализации.

:[image: Схема сайта]

Comment: каждый клик по горизонтальному меню приводит к **повторному исполнению РНР** скрипта и повторной отрисовке страницы. Если надо что-то раскрыть - это все задаётся в РНР

Comment: больше меню, богу меню)

Answer (score 0):

Вам для начала не нужен PHP. Сверстайте сайт как вам нужно, затем просто(или не просто, но это уже тема следующего вопроса) замените свои данные на данные PHP.

PHP это как бы про back часть. Она вам НИКАК не поможет в отрисовке.

Смотрите в сторону javascript